# Google Recapatcha and disabled input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input, recaptcha

I would like to use the new Google Recaptcha. I follow a tutorial to check if the captcha is well validate. Now I want to add or not the disabled attribute to and input. The input need to be disabled when the captcha is wrong, and when the captcha is ok, the input is enabled.

Here is my code for now, but the input doesn't work as I want..

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST' ){
        $key='TA CLE GOOGLE';
        $response=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $gapi='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' .$key. '&response='.$response. '&remoteip='.$ip;
        $json=json_decode(file_get_contents($gapi),true);
        if(!$json[ 'success']){
            echo "
                <script>
                    $(\"input\").prop('disabled',true);
                </script>
            ";
        }
        else{
            echo "
                <script>
                    $(\"input\").prop('disabled',false);
                </script>
            ";
        }
    }
?>
<input id="toto" class="btn btn-block btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Resolve"/>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Move your input field above the php code. Your js is likely running before the input has been added to the dom.  You could also wrap your js in a doc ready if you dont want to move the html.

EDIT:
You could also set a php variable with your current code and use that to output a disabled attribute. For example, add `$disable_field = FALSE;` to the top of your script, use `$disable_field = !$json[ 'success'];` instead of the if else conditional, then output your html like:

```
<input id="toto" class="btn btn-block btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Resolve" <?php if ($disable_field) echo 'disabled="disabled"';?>/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, but I try both of the solution, and none of the both are working..